# Hard Javascript/jQuery Animation (Spinner/Scroller)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Okay, I'm trying to make it so when you click a button it'll spin a div with it's randomized contents and it'll slow down on stop on a specified div, now I have no idea where to start,

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7jjhLUKleg

Any idea how to start? what should my priority be, jQuery or Javascript?

Kind Regards

EDIT: I'm not asking for anyone to spoonfeed me code, I just need an idea on where to start.

Comment: Start with some code. You say that you need to click on a button. Then do it. Create a button with a click event. After that try to make a div spin. Then try to generate random content, ...

Comment: I already did all of this, I need to find a way to make the div contents spin from right to left.

Comment: If you already did this why are you asking **how to start ?** ? Please provide the code you tried

Comment: I need help on the Animation, I haven't done anything for it but I can't seem to think of a right way to do it.

Comment: have you even try to search it on google ?

Comment: Yep, multiple times even, since I turned about eight years old actually. Tho the only thing that pops-up are spinner animations and not the right thing that I am looking for.

Comment: Seriously ? Come on... : **rotate-a-div-using-javascript** on stackoverflow

Comment: It's not rotating that I'm looking for, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7jjhLUKleg

Answer (score 0):

The animation itself can be probably solved easily using [JQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) functions. The animation supports easing, and the "ease out" is what you need. With some CSS, you would create some kind of viewport, and move the elements from right to left until the animation stops.

Let me help you with some starting code: http://jsfiddle.net/dfevruws/1/

The animation command is very simple:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#items" ).animate({
    left: -2000
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "easeOutQuad"
  });
});
```

Probably more interesting than this is how you handle the selected item, but this is a different story, you ask for the Animation.